# JmsTemplate.convertAndSend throws Uncategorized exception - ActiveMQ SpringBoot configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I believe that i messed up with configuration but I cannot get where and how to fix it.
[Here](https://github.com/anagornaia/activemq-practice) you can find code.

> org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occurred during JMS processing; nested exception is javax.jms.JMSException: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://localhost:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

```
at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:311)
at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.convertJmsAccessException(JmsAccessor.java:185)
at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:507)
at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:584)
at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.convertAndSend(JmsTemplate.java:661)
at com.example.jms.activemqpractice.messaging.MessageSender.send(MessageSender.java:16)
```

I know that his one could be marked as duplicate, but I could not find answer that would fix my problem.

Comment: Your activeMq is really up ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `spring.activemq.broker-url=tcp://localhost:61616`

.

> Connection refused:

Simply means that you don't have activemq running on localhost:61616

The `tcp://` scheme means the broker must be running already, usually in another process, or you need to add a broker to your application with the `tcp` transport.

If you just want to use an embedded broker within your application, use

`vm://localhost`

or

`vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false`

if you don't want to persist messages between runs.